# What could cause Windows 7 to hang whenever I install something?

Tags: windows-7

I've had this problem when installing several different programs (iTunes, Adobe Acrobat Reader just to name two).  Regardless of what the program is, the install usually gets at least 90% through the process and then just hangs.

I don't see anything bad in the event log besides the following (and this didn't occur exactly at the time of install):

> wuaueng.dll (964)
>   SUS20ClientDataStore: A request to
>   write to the file
>   "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\DataStore.edb"
>   at offset 16252928
>   (0x0000000000f80000) for 32768
>   (0x00008000) bytes succeeded, but took
>   an abnormally long time (185 seconds)
>   to be serviced by the OS. This problem
>   is likely due to faulty hardware.
>   Please contact your hardware vendor
>   for further assistance diagnosing the
>   problem.

I've run check disk and it passed.  I've had some problems with BIOS settings in the past with Windows 7, but I'm not sure whether that could be related.

Update... I also see this error in the event log:

> Volume Shadow Copy Service error:
>   Unexpected error querying for the
>   IVssWriterCallback interface.  hr =
>   0x80070005, Access is denied. . This
>   is often caused by incorrect security
>   settings in either the writer or
>   requestor process.
>
> Operation:    Gathering Writer Data
>
> Context:    Writer Class Id:
>   {e8132975-6f93-4464-a53e-1050253ae220}
>   Writer Name: System Writer    Writer
>   Instance ID:
>   {33493f01-ac1b-4efb-a378-3053ab03100d}

One last wrinkle.... I see "Previous versions" of c:\ which look like they correspond to the time of attempted installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning Volume Shadow Service off and see what happens. Error #1 looks like a file that's locked when MSI is trying to write to it (though don't discount faulty hardware either).

Error #2 and your previous versions comment make me believe that VSS could be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Chkdsk is not the best disk checker, as it's more oriented towards file system consistency.

You might try to run the freeware [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/), which I've never used.

The best disk test **and repair** program I know is [SpinRite 6.0](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) at $89 with a 30-days money-back guarantee. I've seen it resuscitate hard disks that I was ready to swear were beyond recuperation. It's a boot-cd, and so will work regardless of your operating system.

Comment: Yes, SpinRite.  I've heard of it.  I listen to Steve Gibson's podcast occasionally.  Not sure it's really a HD problem at this point though.

Comment: As I see "security settings" in the message, you might also try to totally deactivate UAC.